# Validation message not showing .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to .net MVC. I am trying to validate a field from the model, but **error** message is not showing. Although the fields are red, the message just not show. Please see bellow :

**The model:**

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "FirstName is required")]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

**The cshtml:**

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added following scripts in the view

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>    
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")' type='text/javascript'>         </script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

And enable validation from web config

```
<appSettings>
........
........
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: **I have :** `<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.18.0/jquery.validate.min.js' type='text/javascript'>         </script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
    ` **and my web config** `<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>`

Comment: Then you are missing jQuery lib, see the first script in my answer